# Xcode cannot parse content to info.pilst

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, parse-platform, compiler-errors

I m new to xcode. I m using xcode 7 and i found this "issue" when i click the project.
[image: here is the image] 
I just add a parse login and it work fine but when i m trying to add a facebook sdk i found the identity had changed. My Parse login is working fine in the simulator and compiler but i m not sure what's the image mean and not sure does it affect the file.
How can i resolve the problem? Also, when i tried to open the info.plist it shows" cannot open infor.plist in different format" does it affect the file or did i do something wrong ?

(i added "< /dict >" back to the info.plist but still happen)

[![info.plist][2]][2]

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
  <plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>en</string>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>info.
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>APPL</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.0</string>
<key>CFBundleSignature</key>
<string>????</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1</string>
<key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
<true/>
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string>LaunchScreen</string>
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
<string>Main</string>
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
<string>armv7</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb1659373867666932</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>1659373867666932</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>Swish</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Can you add the updated plist to the question as text?

Answer (score 0):

You should open you plist file with an editor and check at least if the file respected xml syntax, in other words if it is well formed.

Comment: i found this error when i put the fbsdk code into the info.plist but after i delete it i still happen. I uploaded my plist file.